# How to enable CORS in Mulesoft on application level?

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I need to enable CORS in Mulesoft on the application level. I already have found some solutions by setting CORS on the listener, but it doesn't work for me. Here is my HTTP listener configuration:

> ```
> <http:listener-config name="erp-apoteka-api-httpListenerConfig">
>     <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" protocol="HTTPS"/>
>     <http:listener-interceptors>
>         <http:cors-interceptor>
>             <http:origins>
>                 <http:origin url="http://localhost:3000" accessControlMaxAge="30000">
>                     <http:allowed-methods>
>                         <http:method methodName="GET" />
>                         <http:method methodName="POST" />
>                         <http:method methodName="DELETE" />
>                         <http:method methodName="OPTIONS" />
>                       <http:method methodName="PUT" />
>                     </http:allowed-methods>
>                     <http:allowed-headers >
>                       <http:header headerName="Content-Type" />
>                       <http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />
>                       <http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
>                   </http:allowed-headers>
>                   <http:expose-headers />
>                 </http:origin>
>             </http:origins>
>         </http:cors-interceptor>
>     </http:listener-interceptors>
> </http:listener-config>
> ```

I'm using React and Axios on frontend and when I do some calls, I got this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/api/kategorije' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
KategorijeContainer.tsx:53 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:8081/api/kategorije net::ERR_FAILED
```

My axios settings are this:

```
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
baseURL: BaseRoutes.ApiUrl,
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
responseType: 'json',
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your http:listener-connection protocol is set to HTTPS but your origin is coming from http://localhost.. I'm assuming you're still in your development phase and have no TLS enabled on your mule backend, try changing it to HTTP.